# Here map full screen control

Tags: heremaps

I want to add or enable the full screen control button using here map api

I'm need to add some additional UI components to my map, here is my initialisation : const H = window.H;
const platform = this.platform;

```
    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:

    const map = new H.Map(container, defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
      zoom: 10, // set initial zoom level to show Saudi Arabia
      center: {
        lat: this.coordinatesForm.latitude,
        lng: this.coordinatesForm.longitude,
      }, // set center to Riyadh, Saudi Arabia
      pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    });
```